# How to integrate a custom adapter and custom layout into ListFragment?

Tags: android, adapter, android-listfragment

I am new in Android and I have a ListFragment that can successfully show the items (only text) in the list.

```
//More.class

public class More extends ListFragment{

private ListView mListView;
String android_versions[] = new String[]{"1","2","3","4",};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android_versions);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_listview, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return view;
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter class

```
//ImageAdapter.class

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {super(context, R.layout.more_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("About App")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_about);
        } else if (s.equals("Tools Tutorial")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_about);
        } else if (s.equals("EnfaMama A+ Club")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_app);
        } else if (s.equals("App Technical Contact")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_app);
         }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

and this is my settings for the text and image

```
//more_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tool_settings" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
```

I want to achieve two things here.

1) I have a custom adapter that contains an Image and a Text and I would like to use this adapter. How do I integrate it into More.class?

- I tried

`ImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, android_versions);`

but i get constructor undefined.

2) Correct me if I am wrong, as I understand android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is the default android list, and I would like to use my own custom layout which is R.layout.more_item.

- I tried replacing R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with R.layout.more_item but my application crash.

What should I do? What did I do wrong?

This is my first post, and I apologized if I asked a silly question. I hope I am clear enough to make you understand what I want. I have very low knowledge in Android, so I hope someone could guide me how to do it here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, android_versions);
>
> but i get constructor undefined.

You need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this`, since you are inside a fragment (not in activity)

```
I tried replacing R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with R.layout.more_item but my application crash.
```

you cannot use your custom layout with default ArrayAdapter directly. If that crash occur with `ImageAdapter`, post that crash log.

try like this

```
ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), android_versions);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I tried your codes and it worked! I didn't know that earlier but now I will remember to use getActivity() in Fragment next time. Thank you so much. You've been very helpful. :)